# Are there US-oriented travel planning sites which split a route into daily chunks?

Tags: usa, driving, planning, accommodation, stopovers

I am planning a trip next year to the South-West of the US (starting and ending in SF, with a road tour across the major attractions).

There are several sites to help with the planning (notably [Roadtrippers](https://roadtrippers.com/) which is horribly slow and the addresses matching is horrendous -- but has quite a lot of information). **All the ones I had a look at are missing one key feature: breaking the route into daily chunks.**

All of them give an overall driving time which does not make much sense. It would be better, when planning to start at at 8:00, to know that one is likely to be here and here at 19:00. This would allow, taking into account the time spent on visiting, eating, stopping 73 times for the children to pee - to plan for a motel on the way.

This becomes particularly important when the type of the road is taken into account: 100 km on a highway is different from 100 km in the mountains.

Is such functionality available somewhere?

Comment: that's a good idea.

Comment: I programmed that myself years ago because I had the need. I doubt there is anything out there.

Comment: @Aganju: did you use something like Google Directions API for that? Or just manually stretching the route?

Comment: @Aganju: did you use something like Google Directions API for that? Or just manually stretching the route?

Comment: all own code - that was before Google API. I typed the distances/ travel times to all relevant places in, and each member of the party could pick on a website what he wants to see/do. The code then sequenced the picked list and added overnight stops after each day was filled.

Comment: My website has a tool that allows you to map out trips. It doesn't do what you want though so I'm curious about your need in case it's something I should consider adding.

How would it allow for all those pee stops, eating, sight seeing along the way, when there's so much variability in how different travellers approach drives? Some people prefer to just push through, stopping briefly along the way. While others take it much more slowly.

And because they are daily chunks, do you expect to see a "schedule" view or something similar where it breaks down the trip by days?

Comment: @daamsie: you are right that this is not exact science but it would be enough to be able to add a few expected stops on the way to make it very useful. This is especially the case in countries one does not know very well. As an example, I can easily plan for dive trips across Europe where the highway system is consistent. If driving, say, from Paris to Prague, I can easily imagine where to stop. I will need to drive from SF to Death Valley via Yosemite and have a hard time guessing where I will be at the end of the day (assuming that I will stop for, say, 3 hours at Yosemite Park).

Comment: @daamsie (cont'd) Today I would use Google maps and drag the end point of the route until I reach, say, 6 hours of drive. In the same way, I would be glad to be able to roughly plan the whole trip from SF to Phoenix via Yosemite, Death Valley, LV, Zion Brice, Arches as waypoints and have an idea of how many days it will take assuming 5 hours drive per day in average - and stopping next to a town (not in between).

Comment: @daamsie (cont'd)  Again, in a densely inhabited area like Europe one will always find a place to stay, in the US it may be more difficult in some areas. Please let me know if my longish explanation was not clear - thanks!

Comment: I understand the use. I'm quite reliant on APIs for calculating times though and what you're proposing probably means merging the API provided times (in my case from Openstreetmaps) with real travellers' data to get an estimated time. Unfortunately that's a little beyond my tool right now as it's just not data I have any access to. Google would probably be best placed to be tracking that kind of information. Thanks for expanding on the idea though. I can definitely see how there is a need for something like that. Following this thread to see what others suggest.

Comment: Probably is a dupe of my question [Road trip distance/driving time planning](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/129894/6188).  Oops mine was the dupe lol

Comment: Do AAA's TripTiks do what you want?

Comment: I would have loved something like this last year when we drove across the US - I ended up spending hours (days) on google maps trying to find the places along the route that might be 7-10 hours driving (or whatever it was) and might have accommodation, yet allowing for slower drives for areas full of sites (we wanted to spend more time in Utah, less time in Nebraska, for example).  Did it all on Google Maps, over and over and over

Answer (score 5):

As it is hard to proof a negative, I can only say that there most likely is not website that combines all you want in one.

A map based website that combines routes, travel information and touristic information will do part of what you want. But as you found non of them will cut the route into day sized parts.

That is likely as there are too many options to spend time, it is likely also impossible to work out how fast or slow you will go through traffic. The sites can do an average, but they can not do real time speeds while you are planning ahead of time.

The best alternative for now seems to be to use one of the map sites and work it into daily chunks yourself.
That way you can adjust it for your preferences, allowing you to plan in as much or as little as you like. It is more work for you, as you do not get a ready made list, but it will also allow you to know much better what you are going to do.

You can plan in as many activities as you want or as few or even non at all, every day adjusted to what is available around where you will be that day.

Answer (score 5):

I used https://trips.furkot.com/ to plan my last roadtrip, because it has exactly the feature to break a tour into daily parts. It also has some other features, like to search for and directly book hotels etc. Not sure, what other features you require, it might not have all of them.

Basically, you specify a daily departure time in the morning, and then a time when you want to end the day, and the tool will then show a small hotel icon at around the place where you would then need to stay to finish the tour on time.

Comment: Wow that's really nice. They really only get money from affiliate links? That surely can't last.

Comment: No, you can also buy the premium version (called Furkot Pass), which allows you to have offline maps and a few other things (like also planning fuel stops, having other map types, like satellites). You can get the premium version also if you just book a hotel through them, but usually this is only enabled after the stay is completed, so in my case i just bought the pass itself.